# How to install pip on Redhat Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pip

Please share the steps How to install pip on Redhat Linux.I have tried the below commands.

```
sudo yum install python-pip
yum install python-devel
apt-get install python-pip
```

Regards,
Susovan

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww This question can be closed because it doesn't show what issue was encountered, but **not** because it's off-topic IMO. This question is on-topic because it "directly involve tools used primarily for programming" (`pip` and `python-devel`). https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 9):

You can also use get-pip: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

We use it within virtualenvs in RHEL:

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
$ path-to-specific-python-binary/python get-pip.py`
```